# AWS Multi-Region webapp with centralised login services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We currently have a webapp running in AWS Region Ireland (service for the UK) and are planing to expand the service into the US.

In order to be sure that the US users get a low latency experience  we are considering mirroring the AWS resources used Ireland in the US.

The data for the US users should be stored in the US region, the UK data in Ireland. (There is no need to report across both regions).

We are thinking of building a centralised login services that runs in the Ireland region. After successful login the user will be redirected to the region where his data is stored. (The login service has to know in which region the data is stored)

Has anyone built something similar? Any recommendation how to approach this?
Would Amazon Cognito support such a setup (if we build the login service based on cognito)?

Comment: One suggestion will be use a Location based routing in Route 53 for the login service. So a user from UK will be routed to UK region login service and US will be routed to US region login service.

Comment: Regarding @error2007s 's comment, if US user moves to UK, will they still be able to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Amazon Cognito does not support this out of the box.

But if you use Cognito User Pools with Federated identities the credentials you get can be used in any AWS region. Along with that you can store a custom attribute for the user defining the region to which that user belongs and then redirect them accordingly.